# config.php file working properly in localhost but it's not working on live website

Tags: php, sql, web-hosting

This is config.php file working properly in localhost but it's not
   work live website

```
<?php 
$connect = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('bridgetechnosfot'); ?>
```

Comment: I doubt your "live website" operates a mysql server on the system itself with a root account not protected by a password. At least I strongly hope it does not.

Comment: You could probably find that out yourself if you would not suppress the error using the `@`...

Comment: 1. using `deprecate+removed mysql_*` version is not greate, check on your server that it's available or not and most probably you need to move towards `mysqli_*` Or `PDO`.2. don't supress error with `@` , try to check error and resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
$connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bridgetechnosfot');
if ($connect->connect_error){
        trigger_error('Error:('.$connect->connect_errno.')'.$connect->connect_error);
}
$query = $connect->query("YOUR QUERY..");
```